# Function em onpaste

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho este `input` onde possuo uma `function`, apenas para aceitar números, digitando ela funciona, porém eu gostaria de colocar esta `function` no `onpaste` também, se eu faço colocando `onpaste="return SomenteNumeros(event)"`, não dá certo. Não reconhece, ele deixa passar letras, pontos, vírgulas ,etc.
Seria necessário colocar no `onpaste`, para validar essas informações.

```js
  function SomenteNumeros(event) {
        if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)
            return false;
    }
```

```html
<input  class="form-control" maxlength="8" placeholder="Somente números." OnKeyPress="return SomenteNumeros(event)">
```

Comment: Do jeito que está já bloqueia a colagem de caracteres não numéricos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ou no `onkeyup` (mesmo que vc cole ele tratará):

```js
//Permite Ponto
function somenteNumeros(num) {
  var er = /[^0-9.]/;
  er.lastIndex = 0;
  var campo = num;
  if (er.test(campo.value)) {
    campo.value = "";
  }
}


//Permite virgula
function somenteNumeros2(num) {
  var er = /[^0-9,]/;
  er.lastIndex = 0;
  var campo = num;
  if (er.test(campo.value)) {
    campo.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tes" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `oninput` no lugar de `onkeypress` enviando para a função o elemento como parâmetro através do `this`:

```
oninput="SomenteNumeros(this)"
```

A vantagem do `oninput` é que ele detecta qualquer alteração no campo, seja via mouse ou teclado, enquanto que o `onkeypress` só detecta o teclado.

E na função faça um `.replace` com uma expressão regular eliminando tudo o que não for número:

```
.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

A expressão `/[^\d]/g` seleciona tudo que não é número (`\d`). Desta forma, mesmo colando, via mouse ou teclado, irá eliminar qualquer caractere não numérico.

**Veja:**

```js
function SomenteNumeros(el) {
  el.value = el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="8" placeholder="Somente números." oninput="SomenteNumeros(this)">
```